# What does this block of obfuscated Java function do?

Tags: java, security, function, encryption

First of all this not a homework or any other assignment thats given from another person. This is function from a game applet that i want it to be more secure. With this function you generate a password for the game's handshake part. But using the same encoded password for every player, its just a stupid thing to do. You'd get really open to attacks and this is situation that i am in. This is the why i would like to analyze what this function does and come up with a way that generates a password for every unique connection. So, please try to understand me.

Here is the function:

```
public String g(String paramString)
  {
    boolean bool = d.r;
    try
    {
      if (!bool)
      {
        if (paramString.length() < 3)
        {
          a(tc[2]);
          return "";
        }
        if (bool);
      }
      else
      {
        if (paramString.length() > 200)
        {
          a(tc[3]);
          return "";
        }
        paramString = paramString.toLowerCase();
      }
      String str1 = "";
      String str2 = paramString;
      paramString = paramString.toLowerCase();
      char[] arrayOfChar1 = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ' ' };
      char[] arrayOfChar2 = { 'x', 'f', 'n', 'g', 'd', '9', 's', 'j', 'o', 'q', '5', 'a', 'z', 'w', '6', '0', 'e', '4', 'c', 'r', '1', 'v', 't', '3', 'b', 'y', 'h', '2', 'u', '7', 'm', 'i', 'k', '8', 'l', 'p', '?' };
      char[] arrayOfChar3 = { 'f', 'e', '8', 'r', 'k', 't', '7', 'b', 'c', 'm', 'o', 'q', '2', '3', 'g', 's', 'n', 'x', '0', 'p' };
      char[] arrayOfChar4 = paramString.toCharArray();
      char[] arrayOfChar5 = str2.toCharArray();
      int i1 = 0;
      if (bool);
      do
      {
        int i2 = 0;
        int i3 = 0;
        if (bool);
        do
          do
          {
            if (!bool)
            {
              if (arrayOfChar4[i1] == arrayOfChar1[i3])
                i2 = 1;
            }
            else
            {
              int i4 = paramString.length();
              int i5 = (int)Math.round(Math.random() * 19.0D);
              int i6 = i3 + i5 + i4;
              if (bool);
              String str3;
              do
              {
                do
                  i6 -= arrayOfChar2.length;
                while (i6 >= arrayOfChar2.length);
                str1 = str1 + "" + arrayOfChar3[i5];
                str3 = String.valueOf(arrayOfChar2[i6]);
              }
              while (bool);
              if (arrayOfChar4[i1] != arrayOfChar5[i1])
                str3 = str3.toUpperCase();
              str1 = str1 + "" + str3;
            }
            i3++;
          }
          while (i3 < arrayOfChar1.length);
        while (bool);
        if (i2 == 0)
          str1 = str1 + "\\" + arrayOfChar4[i1];
        i1++;
      }
      while (i1 < arrayOfChar4.length);
      return str1;
    }
    catch (Exception localException)
    {
    }
    return "";
  }
```

And this are the some examples generated by it:

```
    aaa -> cafg89  
    aaa -> ca3eca  
    aaa -> q6fged  
    aaa -> fgg4ow  
    aaaa -> tqp3srmw  
    aaaa -> 75e9rjcz  
    bbb -> o6q00t  
    bbb -> 0tczcz  
    bbbb -> 03o0bzo0  
    bbbb -> rogrt5kq
```

But here are the most suspicious examples:

```
1111111 -> 00000000000000  
222222 -> 000000000000  
33333 -> 0000000000  
5555555 -> m5m5m5m5m5m5m5  
666666 -> m5m5m5m5m5m5  
77777 -> m5m5m5m5m5  
8888 -> m5m5m5m5  
999 -> m5m5m5
```

I am a bit desperate right now thats why i am pushing my luck. Thank you for your every word.

Comment: I didn't get the point, you just wanna to generate a distinct password for each user, why understand this method? Wouldn't your question be something like related to password generation or security check?

Comment: yes. but the applet has the option only for everyone. i'll try to use the setting file through php and put distinct password for each user. but for me to use this, i have to understand the main idea behind this encode algorithm. otherwise the attackers could see the plain text and act upon it.

Comment: There is not enough code to know what this method is doing: What is d.r? The a() method? The tc[] array? Without those, it's impossible to understand.

Comment: ok, meaning if the attackers understand this code they could attack the game?

Comment: i think a is a method for printing some message through tc array. i am not sure about the d.r tho.

Comment: @FranciscoSpaeth exact opposite. if i can understand this code, i can come up with a solution that generates passwords for each connection and this makes it more secure.

Comment: i'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. if you want to make handshake more secure then just replace the function, instead of analyse it

Comment: i dont have any access to the source code and recompile it. thats why i need to use the setting file -which is a txt- through php and put different passwords for each user.

Answer (score 2):

There some doubt that the decompiler has succeeded in generating code that matches the behaviour of the bytecodes.  For instance, the code says `if (bool);` in a couple of places, and it is hard to see why the bytecodes would ever do that.  If we can't trust the decompiled code, then there has to be some doubt in any conclusions that we draw from the code.

---

The other point to make is that your assumption here:

> With this function you generate a password for the game's handshake part. But using the same encoded password for every player, its just a stupid thing to do.

It is clear from the output that you provide that this code does not generate the same output for a given input.  And it would be rather surprising if it did, given that it appears to be repeatedly calling `Random` as part of the scrambling algorithm.

In short, you are attempting to fix a problem that does not exist ... or at least not in the form that you describe.

Comment: which decompiler do you suggest? this was generated by jd-gui.

Comment: I suggest that you read the bytecodes directly.  Decompilers are often confused by obfuscated code.  Not surprising, because this is one of the goals of a good obfuscator.

Comment: You are right about generating random results every time but the password i mean the plain password which we use for getting encoded results is the same for every turn. what i mean is it is not important to change the result every other time since you can see it through sniffers and once you see it, the only option for you is to change the password again. but if i knew how this func works i could   come up with a way that generates random plain texts and encodes it everytime.

Comment: @jamall55 - that doesn't make sense to me.  How would generating random plain texts help?  And what is to stop you from doing it anyway ... and just feeding them to this algorithm?  I fail to see how understanding the algorithm will help you.

Comment: generating a unique password which changes for every other connection.. thats the idea. but now, i could only use one password for every connection. and you should put the encoded pass into setting file. after one connection you make, you can use the password for the future connections from another clients. but what i am trying to achieve is generating a unique passwd for each connection. after you quit, that passwd should be gone and never be used. but for this to be secure, i need to generate encoded passwords which is obligatory. you have to encode a password before you put it in the file.

Comment: @jamall55 - And you have STILL not explained why you need to understand how the "encoded" password is generated.  (Can't you just call the method?). Or even why you can't just generate these strings another way.  But anyway, if you feel that you need to do this, you will probably need to do the hard work yourself; either by understanding the code yourself or reverse engineering the bytecodes by hand yourself.

Comment: i need to understand it because i cant call this method via php. i should come up with the php implementation. i'll try to bytecodes now. hope i can get something that can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

To generate a unique password for every unique connection you could use something like:

```
SHA256(secret + connectionNumber + dateAndTime)
```

`secret` is a fixed secret password that you change as often as required.

`connectionNumber` is a count of the connections made so far that day.

`dateAndTime` is the current data and time in a standard format.

Convert all three to strings, concatenate and apply SHA-256.  That will give you an array of bytes.  If you need text, rather than bytes, then convert using Base64.

For example:

```
String password = Base64(SHA256("myBIGsecret52012-07-23T13:06:25.254Z"));
```